# Variable number of input artifacts into a step

Tags: argo-workflows, argoproj

I have a diamond style workflow where a single step `A` starts a variable number of analysis jobs `B` to `X` using `withParam:`.  The number of jobs is based on dynamic information and unknown until the first step runs. This all works well, except that I also want a single aggregator job `Y` to run over the output of all of those analysis jobs:

```
     B  
    / \
   / C \
  / / \ \
 A-->D-->Y
  \  .  /
   \ . /
    \./
     X
```

Each of the analysis jobs `B`-`X` writes artifacts, and `Y` needs as input all of them. I can't figure out how to specify the input for `Y`. Is this possible? I've tried passing in a JSON array of the artifact `key`s, but the pod gets stuck on pod initialisation. I can't find any examples on how to do this.

`A` creates several artifacts which are consumed by `B`-`X` (one per job as part of the `withParam:`) so I know my artifact repository is set up correctly.

Each of the jobs `B`-`X` require a lot of CPU so will be running on different nodes, so I don't think a shared volume will work (although I don't know much about sharing volumes across different nodes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted the question as a GitHub issue:

https://github.com/argoproj/argo/issues/4120

The solution is to write all the output to an artifact path specific to the job (i.e. the same subdirectory). You then specify that path as the input `key` and argo will unpack all the previous results into a subdirectory. You can use `{{workflow.name}}` to create unique paths.

This does mean you're restricted to a specific directory structure on your artifact repository, but for me that was a small price to pay.

For a full working solution see sarabala1979's answer on the GitHub issue.